# Angular 4 get dom element

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application

Hi i'm trying to set focus on an input element once the edit button is clicked on an Angular 4 application.

First i tried Renderer2, but it doesn't seem to work for this purpose.

Now I'm trying to get it using @ViewChild, I'm always getting value as undefined.

I event tried implementing AfterViewInit and logging the element immediately once loaded, but still I'm getting 'undefined'. Please help..

```
        import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, Renderer2, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';
        import { DataService } from '../data.service';
        import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

        @Component({
            selector: 'app-artist-list-item',
            template: `
                    <button class="w3-button w3-circle w3-orange" (click)="edit(nameInput)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                    <span *ngIf="editable">
                        <input  class="name" #nameInput (keyup)="onKey(nameInput.value)" (keypress)="inputEnter($event)" [value]="artist.name">
                        <button class="w3-button w3-green btn-save" (click)="save()">Save</button>
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="!editable">
                        {{artist.name}}
                    </span>
            `,
            styleUrls: ['./artist-list-item.component.scss']
        })
        export class ArtistListItemComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

            @Input() artist: any;
            @Output() onDelete = new EventEmitter();
            @Output() onEdit = new EventEmitter();
            @Output() onSave = new EventEmitter();
            @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput;

            public editable: boolean = false;
            name: any = '';

            constructor(private Data: DataService, private rd: Renderer2) { }

            ngAfterViewInit() {
                console.log(this.nameInput);
            }

            ngOnInit() {
            }

            edit(el) {
                console.log(el);
                console.log(this.nameInput);
                this.editable = true;
                this.name = this.artist.name;
            }

        }
```

by the way i have removed the code where i tried to set focus.

```
            edit(el) {
                console.log(el);
                console.log(this.nameInput);
                this.nameInput.focus();
                this.editable = true;
                this.name = this.artist.name;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, `nameInput` will only be there when `editable` is true. Also here your default value for editable is set to false(`public editable: boolean = false`). So the element is not even present in DOM, which is the reason why it is giving you undefined even when you call in `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
 <span *ngIf="editable">
     <input  class="name" #nameInput (keyup)="onKey(nameInput.value)" (keypress)="inputEnter($event)" [value]="artist.name">
     <button class="w3-button w3-green btn-save" (click)="save()">Save</button>
 </span>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer not below one can you suggest  a way to resolve this

Answer (score 9):

You need to access the `nativeElement` property on the element you defined within your `@ViewChild` declaration to manipulate the actual DOM element. Calling @ViewChild alone just creates an `ElementRef` to an element within the DOM. Hence why you have to access the `nativeElement` property of the `ElementRef` to manipulate the DOM element. For example:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.nameInput.nativeElement);
}
```

[This is a great article on DOM Abstractions in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02).